Connection between factorials and gamma function?
This is the version of Stirling's approximation that is familiar to me:
$$
n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n, \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$$
Recently I saw a version based on the Gamma function and I am not sure where it comes from.
$$
\Gamma(x) \sim \sqrt{2\pi} x^{x-1/2} e^{-x}, \quad \text{as } x \to \infty.
$$
I tried myself:

Stirling's approximation for factorials:
$$ n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n $$
Relationship between Gamma function and factorials for positive integers:
$$ \Gamma(x) = (x-1)! $$
Substitute Stirling's approximation for $(x-1)!$:
$$ \Gamma(x) = (x-1)! \sim \sqrt{2\pi(x-1)} \left( \frac{x-1}{e} \right)^{x-1} $$
As $x \to \infty$, we can loosely state that $x-1 \sim x$.
Replace all $x-1$ with $x$ expect in the exponent:
$$ \sim \sqrt{2\pi x} \left( \frac{x}{e} \right)^{x-1} $$
Expand:
$$ \sim \sqrt{2\pi x} \cdot \frac{x^{x-1}}{e^{x-1}} $$
Separate the $\sqrt{x}$ term:
$$ \sim \sqrt{2\pi} \cdot \sqrt{x} \cdot \frac{x^{x-1}}{e^{x-1}} $$
Combine the $x$ terms in the numerator:
$$ \sim \sqrt{2\pi} \cdot x^{x-1/2} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{x-1}} $$
Rewrite $e^{x-1}$ as $e^x/e$:
$$ \sim \sqrt{2\pi} \cdot x^{x-1/2} \cdot \frac{e}{e^x} $$
Finally, $1-x = -x$ for large $x$. Thus:
$$ \Gamma(x) \sim \sqrt{2\pi} \cdot x^{x-1/2} \cdot e^{-x} $$

Is this all correct?

Just use $\Gamma(x)=(x-1)!=x!/x$. Note that this derivation of the asymptotics works only for positive integer $x$.

Btw your derivation is incorrect in multiple places. For instance clearly $e^{1-x} \sim e^{-x}$ is not true.

thank you Gary ...

I indicated a simple solution in the comments. Alternatively, you may verify that
$$
\sqrt {2\pi (n - 1)} \left( {\frac{{n - 1}}{{\rm e}}} \right)^{n - 1}  = \sqrt {2\pi }\, n^{n - 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - n} \cfrac{{\rm e}}{{\left( {1 + \cfrac{1}{{n - 1}}} \right)^{n - 1} }}\sqrt {1 - \frac{1}{n}} ,
$$
which implies the result.
